# Autocomplete for mobile web apps

Tags: javascript, web-applications, mobile

Is there a library (like Wink Toolkit, Sencha Touch or jQuery Mobile) that offers autocomplete solutions for web apps out of the box?

I need to apologize because I forgot to add its all about a mobile web app.

Answer (score 2):

The question is excellent. I'm just currently dealing with the very same design problem. Current auto-complete solutions work very poorly on mobile devices (if at all).

**Luckily there is jQuery Mobile for which you can get [jQM Autocomplete](http://www.andymatthews.net/code/autocomplete/) as a plugin**.  See also [accompanying design notes](http://www.andymatthews.net/read/2012/03/27/jQuery-Mobile-Autocomplete-now-available).

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) has [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Comment: Hi, i ment a solution for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

there are in fact several.

jQuery UI has auto complete.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Ajax ControlToolkit has autocomplete control (for c#)

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Mootools auto complete

http://jsfiddle.net/fabiomcosta/eZpuL/3/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used any autocomplete function for Sencha Touch myself but I know that there is a feature called "combobox" which has that functionality and Sencha Touch developers could use.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing autocomplete on mobile makes you have into account that user is more prone to typing errors, and also has a changing connection.

I made an autocomplete with jQuery UI autocomplete but it performed poorly on mobile. Maybe you could have a different experience with it.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6545344/1197775

Answer (score 0):

YUI3 AutoComplete helps me, this works good on my iphone

demo (( YUI2 )) :: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/autocomplete/ac_basic_xhr.html

tutorial (( YUI3 )) :: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/autocomplete/

hope this helps n__n

Answer (score -2):

jQuery UI library has a autocomplete widget. Check it [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Comment: Please check it yourself on mobile.... On my Kitkat Android 4.4.2 Phone, The autocomplete looks awfull.....