# Autocomplete for mobile web apps

Tags: javascript, mobile, autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting jQueryUi Autocomplete to work with jQueryMobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994865/getting-jqueryui-autocomplete-to-work-with-jquerymobile)

Is there a out of the box solution (examples) for autocomplete for "mobile" web apps like for iphone, android 2.1+ devices,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a normal jQuery library should work. Smashing Magazine had a good article on how to implement it in the best way forward.

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/04/27/tap-ahead-design-pattern-mobile-auto-suggest-on-steroids/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter

Comment: maybe get the link to work

Comment: Link is no longer dead but downvoting because this answer is essentially just a link to an article

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this plugin for instance: [jquery autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete)

Answer (score 0):

I have recently completed a mobile web app which uses the standard autocomplete function rolled into jQuery UI -- works well.